# How can I toggle hide/show a div tag and move another at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have a script below, that hides a DIV tag (in this case "foo") when hyperlink is clicked. Then shows when the link is clicked once more.

This script works perfectly for my uses, but need to amend the coding slightly, to move another ("in this case "bar").

I'd like to move the DIV tag id "bar" to another location on the page. Clicking the link again, I want it to move back again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block');
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is a foo</div>
<div id="bar">This is a bar</div>
```

Comment: its ok (check it here http://jsfiddle.net/uW9BM/), what is your error?

Comment: There isn't any error's, but not sure how to add positioning to the DIV tag ID "bar" when the hyperlink is pressed.

Comment: "I'd like to move the DIV tag id "bar" to another location on the page. Clicking the link again, I want it to move back again." Where do you want to move it to?

Comment: @Echelon Do you like something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uW9BM/7/

Comment: I'm such a muppet and not explaining myself properly.

Comment: Mehdi Yeganeh you is the man!!! Thankyou soo much for this mega-quick reply.

Comment: I have now added this to my site and works like a charm. Tested perfectly. Its used to show and hide a scrolling menu-bar then hide it again. Thus the frame window fills the space. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the DIV's CSS position to relative/absolute/fixed/whatever and use the CSS method to change the left/right top/bottom properties of the DIV at the same time?